# This code only sees the first event that is in my calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to fetch multiple events from my google calendar and I have written code that allows me to connect from google to my own calendar.

However, the code I use to link between calendars seems to be only fetching the first event. It does however recognize all the events in my calendar.

I have tried a lot of things but mostly all failed. I am new to coding and anything would be helpful.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
events = []
x = []
RemName = ' '
DATE = 0
size = 0
def main():
    global x
    global DATE
    global RemName
    global events
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time

    print('Getting the upcoming 100 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=100, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()

    events = events_result.get('items', [])
    size = len(events_result)


    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))

        x = start, event['summary']
        print(x)

        z=x[0].split('-')
        z1=z[2].split('T')
        c = x[0].split(':')
        v= x[0].split('T')
        y=int(z[0])
        m=int(z[1])
        d=int(z1[0])
        t= z1[1]
        D1= datetime.date(y,m,d)
        t1= t.split(':')
        hr = int(t1[0])
        mi = int(t1[1])
        sc = int(t1[2])
        msc = .25
        D2 = time(hr, mi, sc)
        D3 =  datetime.datetime(y,m,d,hr,mi,sc)
        DATE = D3


        return Date

def RemName():
    global x
    RemName = str(x[1])
    return RemName
```

There are no errors and it works perfectly but it only grabs the first event and that's it. I think the issue is in the loop `for events in event`.

Comment: Thats not all the code so dont worry everything is functional. I just want info and assistance on getting multiple events

Comment: You're returning `Date` (which is never defined, BTW) _on the very first iteration of the `for` loop_. So, once you return, the loop terminates along with the whole function

Comment: hmm i see so how would i go about it. i need the DATE var to be able to use in my other lines of code.

Comment: Put them in a list and return the list.

Comment: Where do you call `main()`? Why does it need to return anything?

Comment: put the variable in a list?

Comment: umm so i need it to return a variable that is a date. once i get that variable i. import the var to a diffenet code and use it for a calendar

Comment: @mudharmuhi, it's not about the variable, it's about the fact that you're returning stuff _at the very first iteration of the loop_. This doesn't make much sense, because the loop _won't loop_ if you return from it like that, so you could safely replace `for event in events` with `event = events[0]`, right? But that's not what you intended to write, is it?

Comment: yes you are right. i need it to go through the loop and give me a date in the var DATE and then i can use that however i want and keep going untill no more events in calendar

Comment: i think i jst have to make a list like that person said thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason that you have the return inside the for loop? Move that out and build the solution inside the loop. Send the array you and return the final array of events.

Comment: Thanks but i figured it out